# regular expression for all characters except ^

Tags: jquery

i'm working input validation that validates all characters except 
^ (cap) in jquery  . I've tried somany RE but not succeded. 
thanks
this is RE i'm Using

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9_\/%*(){}.,;]/
```

RE should not allow ^ at any position
Ex:abc^def
      ^abc
      abc^

Answer (score 3):

Coincidentally, a leading `^` in a character class means “match any character that is *not* one of these characters”. So your regular expression would be `[^^]`.

Or, if you’re looking to ensure that a string doesn’t contain *any* carets, just use `str.indexOf("^") === -1`.

Answer (score 0):

please try this :

```
/[^^]/
```

it's simply say all except ^

Comment: Surprisingly, you don't need to escape a cap.

Answer (score 0):

```
[^^]
```

Will do it. It looks weird because the first hat is the regex 'not' statement and the second hat is the hat you are not matching. Apparently you don't have a escape the hat with a \, so that is neat.

If you want to check that the whole string doesn't use a hat do this:

```
^[^^]$
```

Which I have to say ranks up there on cryptic regular expressions. The beginning ^ and the end $ are the anchors.

Comment: *“you have to escape the second hat”* You don’t, actually.

Answer (score 0):

The ^ character means "not" in a regular expression, so you can simply do:

```
var str = "asdf";
/^[^\^]+$/i.test(str); // True

str = "asd^f";
/^[^\^]+$/i.test(str); // False
```